# What is the value of the variable result after the following code is executed?

Tags: java, loops

```
int count = 0, result = 0;
while(count <= 10)
{
    if(count % 2 ==0)
    {
        result = result + count;
    }
    else
    {
        result = 0;
    }
    count = count + 2;
}
System.out.println("Result: " + result);
```

Can someone explain why the answer is 30?

Comment: run it in debug mode, you will get the answer.

Comment: how do you do that? I'm using Jcreater.

Comment: You don't even need a debugger, just step through it manually and you will see how the value is 30. Only few iterations and you will get to know.

Comment: Lacking a debugger, put a `System.out.println("count=" + count + ", result=" + result);` after the `count = count + 2` line, and you'll see how the variables change for each iteration.

Comment: It clearly sums the even numbers from 0 to and including 10. The if(count % 2 == 0) condition will be true every time since you're adding 2 to an already even number each time.

Comment: I suggest you use an IDE with a debugger in it.  There is plenty of free ones.  You will have bugs in the future and you really need to try to debug them first.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, count is `0`. `0 % 2 == 0`, so the `if` block is executed (and not the `else` block). `result + count` evaluates to `0`, so `result` is set to `0`. Repeat with `2` (`count + 2`) and this is added to `result`, as `2 % 2 == 0`.

For every value of `count`, `count % 2 == 0` evaluates to `true`. This is because you are incrementing it by `2` each time, so it will always remain even. Because of this, the `else` block is **completely redundant** and should be removed. Anyhow, what you are doing is summing all even numbers up to 10 (inclusive, as you use `<=`). This is 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + 10 = 30, which is printed.

Side note: assignments which look like this (where `v` is a variable , `o` is an operator and `e` is an expression) may be simplified:

```
v = v o e;
```

is essentially (can anyone link me that question explaining the difference involving casting?) equivalent to

```
v o= e;
```

for arithmetic operators.

Answer (score 0):

`count` starts at `0` and number `2` is added to it at each iteration. The loop stops when `count` is equal or higher than `10`. Therefore the values of `count` will be :

```
0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
```

These are all even numbers so `count % 2 == 0` will be true.

`result` starts at `0` and at each iteration `count` is added to it. Therefore the final `result` will be the sum of all the above numbers. And

```
0 + 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + 10 = 30
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added two lines of code into yours and the code is now self-explaining.

```
int count = 0, result = 0;
    while(count <= 10)
    {
        if(count % 2 ==0)
        {
            result = result + count;
            System.out.println("count%2 " + count%2 + " and Count is " + count + " and Result is " + result);
        }
        else
        {
            result = 0;
            System.out.println("count%2 " + count%2 + " Count is " + count + " and Result is " + result);
        }
        count = count + 2;
    }
    System.out.println("Result: " + result);
```

and it prints to the console following output

```
count%2 0 and Count is 0 and Result is 0
count%2 0 and Count is 2 and Result is 2
count%2 0 and Count is 4 and Result is 6
count%2 0 and Count is 6 and Result is 12
count%2 0 and Count is 8 and Result is 20
count%2 0 and Count is 10 and Result is 30
Result: 30
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It simply increments `result` by every even number **from zero to 10**. And by adding those numbers together, you get, *well*, **30**.

Even numbers between 0 and 10 include:

```
0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
```

by adding them all up, you get:

```
0 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 10 = 30
```

You can even *prove* this by **keeping track** of `result` as you go along. See below.

```
int count = 0, result = 0;
do {
    if (count % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Result went from " + result + " to " + (result += count));
        continue;
    }
    result = 0;
    System.out.println("Result is now " + 0);
} while ((count += 2) <= 10);
System.out.println("Result: " + result);
```